# Access string variable from bash in jenkinsfile groovy script

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, groovy

I'm building several android apps in a docker image using gradle and a bash script. The script is triggered by jenkins, which runs the docker image.
In the bash script I gather information about the successes of the builds. I want to pass that information to the groovy script of the jenkinsfile.
I tried to create a txt file in the docker container, but the groovy script in the jenkinsfile can not find that file.
This is the groovy script of my jenkinsfile:

```
script {
    try {
        sh script:'''
        #!/bin/bash
        ./jenkins.sh
        '''
    } catch(e){
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
    } finally {
        String buildResults = null
        try {
            def pathToBuildResults="[...]/buildResults.txt"
            buildResults = readFile "${pathToBuildResults}"
        } catch(e) {
            buildResults = "error receiving build results. Error: " + e.toString()
        } 
    }
}
```

In my jenkins.sh bash script I do the following:

```
[...]
buildResults+=" $appName: Build Failed!" //this is done for several apps
echo "$buildResults" | cat > $pathToBuildResults //this works I checked, if the file is created
[...]
```

The file is created, but groovy cannot find it. I think the reason is, that the jenkins script does not run inside the docker container.

How can I access the string buildResults of the bash script in my groovy jenkins script?

Comment: are you getting the jenkinsfile from a git repo? or is the script hardcoded in the job configuration?

Comment: It's coming from a git repo

Comment: then you might have to checkout the sh and the text file together with the jenkinsfile. Keep them together in the git repo that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that you have in order to avoid the need to read the results file is to modify your `jenkins.sh` script to print the results to the output instead of writing them to a file and then use the `sh` step to capture that output and use it instead of the file.
Something like:

```groovy
script {
    try {
        String buildResults = sh returnStdout: true, script:'''
           #!/bin/bash
           ./jenkins.sh
           '''
        // You now have the output of jenkins.sh inside the buildResults parameter
    } catch(e){
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
    }
}
```

This way you are avoiding the need to handle the output files and directly get the results you need, which you can then parse and use however you need.

Comment: It worked, thank you